# Docker image run but nothing on my Chrome

Tags: docker

I run a docker on my machine

[image]

When i want to acces to my docker `http://127.0.0.1:8888` i have error
[image]

Why it's wrong ?

***Dockerfile:***

```
FROM tomcat:9-jre8
RUN echo "export JAVA_OPTS=\"-Dapp.env=staging\"" > /usr/local/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh  
# Copy to images tomcat path
ADD /target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myProject.war
EXPOSE 8888
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Comment: In your screenshot there is also a port 8080 mentioned, did you try this?

Comment: @Myonara yes , i try this port but nothing

Comment: Try replacing `ADD` with `COPY`. It would be nice if you could include container logs to the OP. `docker logs containerId`

Comment: I'd check the catalina.sh script. Make sure it's biding to the host 0.0.0.0 and running on port 8888. The issue could also be your docker host ip is something different to localhost.

Comment: @BenLewisWatson i modify `/conf/server.xm`at line `<Connector port="8888" protocol="HTTP/1.1"[...]` but always the same error

Comment: Can you share the command you ran to run the docker container. Tomcat runs on 8080 unless specified otherwise. What is running on port 8888?

Comment: @MohitMutha command: `"docker run --publish=8888:8888 -d registry.gitlab.com/myproject/registry:develop`

Comment: I can see from your screenshot that 8080 is also exposed. Can you try changing the mapping to --publish 8080:8080 and try accessing `http://localhost:8080`. I think you will get the result you are looking for.

Comment: @MohitMutha ok it's works but how can modify expose port ?

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tomcat runs http on the port 8080 by default. You should change your mapping to port 8080

for eg. 
`docker run -p 8080:8080 <your image name>`

If you want tomcat to run on a port other than 8080 you will need to edit the `server.xml` and change the port. I will not recommend to do that in the docker container. Rather keep tomcat running on default  port and change the port mapping. So if you want the service to be exposed on port 8888 on the local machine then change the mapping to

`docker run --publish=8888:8080 -d registry.gitlab.com/myproject/registry:develop`

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to run tomcat-9 in docker with 8080 port and was able to do that.

1. I cloned some sample git-hub link, which has sample hello-world program.

git clone https://github.com/efsavage/hello-world-war

2. Created docker file with entries given above. Just Exposed port as 8080 (Tomcat default port)

```
FROM tomcat:9-jre8
RUN echo "export JAVA_OPTS=\"-Dapp.env=staging\"" > /usr/local/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh
ADD /target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myProject.war
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

3. Built docker image.

```
docker build -t tomcat_image .
```

4. Run docker image

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 tomcat_image:latest
```

5. Access "http://127.0.0.1:8080/" in web browser, I used google chrome. Voila!! It worked. Please find below screenshot

[image]

Hope this helps!!

Update : Tried with 8888 port, It worked!!. As suggested by @Mohit Mutha , you need to run docker run command by mapping the port with 8080.

```
docker run -p 8888:8080 tomcat_image:latest
```

Attached new screenshot. [image]